Microsoft SMTP OAuth2 authentication in C# with MailKit fails always
I want to send email via my Microsoft email account. Therefor I use MailKit and OAuth2. The problem is, every time, I try to authenticate myself to send emails I get the authentication error:
authentication error
After acquiring the token I get an AuthenticationResult that just contains the AccessToken but the Account is null. I am not sure if this is the problem. I am not sure at all what the problem is.
What have I done?

I created an application in Microsoft Entra: Created a client secret and set the API permissions

enter image description here

Checked all necessary settings I know that the SMTP Authentication works. All settings are set so it must be possible that the SMTP Auth works

Implemented the function to get the OAuth2 Token from this application to authenticate myself

Implemented the function to send the email via Mailkit

I've been looking for a solution for almost 2 weeks and I found many resources but it couldn't fix my problem. I don't want a Public authentication flow that the user must authenticate himself in the browser. I want to do it directly from the backend.


This is the C# code - function to get the access token:
var clientId = ""; // Azure App Client ID
var tenantId = ""; // Azure Tenant ID
var clientSecret = ""; // Azure App Client Secret

var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0";
var scopes = new[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" }; 

IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .Build();

return await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

Function to send the email via MailKit
MimeMessage email = new();
email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(model.UserName, _configuration.GetValue<string("Smtp:ReceiverEmail")));
email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(_configuration.GetValue<string>("Smtp:ReceiverName"), _configuration.GetValue<string>("Smtp:ReceiverEmail")));
email.Subject = $"New feedback";

BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new()
{
    HtmlBody = @"Body"
};

email.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await GetAccessToken();
var oAuth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(_configuration.GetValue<string>("Smtp:ReceiverEmail"), authenticationResult.AccessToken);

using SmtpClient smtpClient = new();
smtpClient.Connect(_configuration.GetValue<string>("Smtp:Host"), _configuration.GetValue<int>("Smtp:Port"));
smtpClient.Authenticate(oAuth2);
smtpClient.Send(email);
smtpClient.Disconnect(true);


Did you follow all of the instructions at https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md ?

I have exact the same issue so following this. And yes, I did follow the instructions.

Yes, I did. I still get this error.
